# How to suppress Wagtail internal deprecation notices?

Tags: wagtail

In recent releases from the 4.x and now 5.x series, there have been many Wagtail deprecation notices shown when running Django management commands like `runserver`.

For example

> .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wagtail/search/index.py:301: RemovedInWagtail60Warning: The partial_match option on SearchField has no effect and will be removed. Use AutocompleteField instead

While I want to see deprecation notices related to my project code, the Wagtail internal deprecations are not actionable.

How can I suppress the Wagtail internal deprecation warnings?

Comment: Are you sure this warning isn't being triggered by a SearchField definition in your own code? It may just be that the warning isn't being raised at the correct level of the stack trace, so it's appearing to come from Wagtail's code rather than your project...

Comment: I'll double-check, thanks :-)

Comment: I've removed all usage of `partial_match` in the project, but the warning persists. Here is the project code search showing zero hits for `partial_match`: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AWesternFriend%2FWF-website+partial_match&type=code

Comment: Looks like you have wagtailmedia set at version 0.14.0 in your poetry.lock file - you should upgrade this to the new 0.14.1, which [removes the partial_match declarations](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtailmedia/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0141---2023-05-05).

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by a more thorough code and dependency audit.